# Python3 GRPC 0.0 float sending

Tags: python, python-3.x, grpc

I made `.proto` file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package utils;

service Utils {
  rpc TextSimilarity (TextSimilarityUtilsRequest) returns (TextSimilarityUtilsResponse);
}

message TextSimilarityUtilsRequest {
  string source1 = 1;
  string source2 = 2;
}

message TextSimilarityUtilsResponse {
  float similarity = 1;
}
```

and generated `.py` files via:

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I source/protos --python_out=source/protos/generated --grpc_python_out=source/protos/generated source/protos/client/utils.proto
```

I also realised basic GRPC server using this [guide](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/basics/)

So, this service calculates similarity between two strings *(via difflib)*
and sends the result. When result is greater then 0.0 service works good, but when result is 0.0 - I get `{}`.

**Success test:**
Input:

```
{
    "source1": "1234321",
    "source2": "13451435"
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "similarity": 0.5333333611488342
}
```

**Failed test:**
Input:

```
{
    "source1": "-",
    "source2": "13451435"
}
```

Output:

```
{}
```

Just for sure I manually sent 0.0 as result:

```
def TextSimilarity(self, request, context):
     return TextSimilarityUtilsResponse(similarity=0.0)
```

and got the same response.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Normally, the request/response classes based on the .proto file (i.e. `TextSimilarityUtilsResponse`) are defined in the auto-generated module (i.e. `*_pb2.py`)